# Load HTML5 Table Dynamically from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in ASP.Net MVC4 , In my view I have a table , want to  load that table from 
but not loading after success.

```
<div id="groupTable"> <table> table columns and rows <table></div>


$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: { groupNames: JSON.stringify(groubyNames), page: JSON.stringify(page) },
            success: function(data) {
                   $('#groupTable').load(data); // not refreshing table withdata
            },
            error: function(request, status, error) {

                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the load to an html call

Edit: This is how you create a table with json data

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: { groupNames: JSON.stringify(groubyNames), page: JSON.stringify(page) },
                success: function(data) {
                     var table = $('<table/>');
                     $(data).each(function() {
                           var row = $('<tr/>');
                           row.append('<td>' + this.Value + '</td>');
                           row.append('<td>' + this.Value + '</td>');
                     });
                     table.append(row);                   
                     $('#groupTable').html(table); // not refreshing table withdata
                },
                error: function(request, status, error) {

                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: What data are you getting back in the success function. Can you verify that this is the html table you're expecting.

Comment: var model = _unitOfWork.MenuSetRepository.Get().ToPagedList(groups, page, 10);

            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);
            return json;

Comment: @ineffablep i mean can you debug the javascript with maybe a console.log to see what the server response is

Comment: @ineffablep also Jquery doesn't know how to build a table from json data. You should be returning html or creating the table in your success function.

Comment: Hi, I am returning   public interface IPagedList : IEnumerable
    {
        int PageIndex { get; }
        int PageSize { get; }
        int TotalCount { get; }
        int TotalPages { get; }
        bool HasPreviousPage { get; }
        bool HasNextPage { get; }
        string GroupByNames { get; }
        Dictionary<string, IEnumerable> Group { get; }
    }